# Magento 2 - Get Rating for each review

Tags: magento2, ratings

Hi I am trying to get ratings for each review. I am able to get the reviews for each product.
This is my review variable `$_review` but when I tried to get rating it doesn't work. The below code should work, but it returns `Error filtering template: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

`<?php if (count($_review->getRatingVotes())) : ?>`

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I am missing something on the function. I am posting the full function here:

```
public function getReviewCollection($productId){
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
        $collection = $this->_reviewCollection->create()
            ->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
            )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $productId
            )->setDateOrder()
            ->addRateVotes();

        return $collection->getItems(); //Get all review data of product
    }
```